# Get url on page change

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the URL of the current page in the foreground tab from a Chrome extension.

I am able to do it, but it keeps displaying the alert over and over again.  I just want it to show once each time a new page is loaded.

This is what I have right now, but it fires a bunch of times for each page load.  I set the status to "complete" but that didn't seem to help.

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true, 'status': "complete"}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;

    alert(url);
  });
});
```

I don't know of any way to know when a new page was loaded without putting it into a tabs.onUpdated which fires constantly.

Comment: Remove chrome.tabs.query and instead check if (changeInfo.status === 'complete')

Comment: Thanks,  @wOxxOm that works